# Get lines of change from a Git diff file for a GitHub repo without using git command

Tags: python, git, diff

##### The goal

I am building a git stats script in Python that can only access the historical git diff patches, so basically files **[like this](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/octocat/Hello-World/pull/2285.diff)**

```
diff --git a/README b/README
index 980a0d5f..fef29374 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
 Hello World!
+
+Hello planet! - DD
\ No newline at end of file
```

##### What do I want exactly?

1. Take a list of git diff files as input
2. Calculate how many lines were changed (optional), added and removed in each diff file
3. Sum it all up
4. Print "total lines added = X, total lines removed = Y" etc.

##### Constraints

The system running this script does not have access to the git repository, nor does it have git installed - introducing an interesting complication.

I have no issues with accessing the API through Python or writing code to manually calculate things. The only issue I have is what I mentioned above.

The repository is hosted on GitHub, and usage of GitHub-specific facilities is allowed.

##### Other sources

I checked, and so I know there were many similar questions on this topic. I'm just having trouble finding what I'm looking for in Python, without using `git` in the repository directly... *(happy to close this if someone can point me to a solution)*

---

So then, any ideas? I assume I can just manually parse each of the diff files and sum it up, but I'm hoping for a silver bullet from a git magician!

Comment: A "git magician" will tell you to use `git`, not code if from scratch.

Comment: @Nic3500 that's true I guess. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that GitHub API already offers these diff stats without the need to have `git` installed or repository checked out locally.

**[GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#list-pull-requests-files)**

Since this is good enough for my case, I'm going to use it. New answers are still welcome though.

Comment: @david-fong This answer solves the problem for me, but it's a workaround for the original issue. I think I clearly stated in the answer that I'm looking forward to new/better answers. Please don't assume what other people will think while reading, they all have commenting power after all. This workaround does not fully address the original question. I see that you have now edited the question to adjust it for the assumption you made. Please don't change the context of the question through editing. It is not related to GitHub and I am still hoping there is a better solution with pure git.